# Apple to Windows External Hard disk file system error

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a Toshiba 1tb hdd. I bought an apple laptop few weeks ago and the hdd has been working properly.  Today I wanted to move some files from my old windows pc to the mac.  When I connected the hdd to windows, the disk management utility showed it as RAW filesystem. I connected it back to Mac and checked the Disk Utility application. It showed me that the drive is in NTFS filesystem.  How do I get it to work in my windows?

Edit: Its my external hdd.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get it to work with Windows and Mac, you need to use FAT32 or exFAT for the drive format.

Comment: But why does it show NTFS in Mac but RAW in Windows?

Comment: Which computer did you format it on?  If you don't have any data on it, I would go ahead, plug it into the PC, format it as FAT32, then start using it.